# Prove by contradiction that if $a$ is rational, then $a^2 \neq a + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove by contradiction that if $a$ is rational, then $a^2 \neq a + 1$.

I can see how can I solve it for integers (dividing into to cases: even and odd). However, since a is rational, I'm expressing it as c/d, and I can't use the even and odd logic anymore since the numbers might be fractions.
Would love to get a direction.
Thanks!

Comment: $\pm1$ is not a root of $a^2-a-1=0$.

Comment: if $a=\frac cd$ is reduced, then how can you express $a^2$ and $a+1$ as reduced fractions?  Can they be the same?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $a^2=a+1,a\in \Bbb Q$ then we have$$a^2-a+{1\over 4}={5\over 4}\implies \left|a-{1\over 2}\right|={\sqrt{5}\over 2}\in\Bbb Q$$which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If $a^2=a+1$ with $a\in\Bbb R$, then $a=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}2$.

If $a$ were rational, then $2a-1=\pm\sqrt5$ would be rational, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=\frac cd$ were a reduced rational root, then
$$
c^2-cd-d^2=0
$$
implies both $c|d^2$ and $d|c^2$, which is only possible in the trivial case, so that $a=\pm 1$. Which obviously is not a root with either sign.

Comment: Can you please explain "implies both |2 and |2, which is only possible in the trivial case, so that =±1. Which obviously is not a root with either sign."?

Comment: $c^2=(c+d)d$ and $d^2=(c-d)c$ along with the assumption that $c$ and $d$ are co-prime gives $d=\pm1$ for $d|c^2$ and $c=\pm 1$ for $c|d^2$, together $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for this elementary question, but what does |2 stands for?

Comment: It means "$c$ divides (into) the square of $d$", which is rather hard to do if $c$ and $d$ do not share any prime factor.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$a$ cannot be an integer  since
$$a(a-1)=1 \implies$$
$$(a=1 \wedge a-1=1 )\vee (a=-1\wedge a-1=-1$$
which is not possible.

If $a=\frac cd$ with $c \wedge d=1$ and $a^2=a+1$, then

$$c^2=d(c+d)$$

now use Gauss Theorem :

If $A|BC$ and $(A\wedge B)=1$ then $A|C$.

Comment: What Gauss theorem? He has several tens *at least*, so what one are you thinking of here?

Comment: @DonAntonio I edited .{}{}{}

Comment: That theorem is Gauss'?? Never heard of it with that name...

Comment: @DonAntonio How do you call it ? Bezout ?

Comment: You could also cite the theorem that for a polynomial with integer coefficients $0=p_dx^d+....+p_0$, in a rational solution $\frac cd$ you have that $c$ divides $p_0$ and $d$ divides $p_d$. Since these coefficients are $1$ ...

Comment: @LutzL Thanks a lot. Good night

Answer (score 1):

Of course this problem may be readily solved *via* the observation that

$a^2 = a + 1 \Longrightarrow a^2 - a - 1 = 0, \tag 1$

and applying the quadratic formula to obtain

$a = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}, \tag 2$

clearly not a rational number.  This line of reasoning provides us with the shortest possible proof I can think of.

Nevertheless, I also feel it is far more engaging to pursue the desired result using only the methods and techniques of truly elementary number theory, so here we go:

Suppose then that the equation

$a^2 = a + 1 \tag 3$

is possessed of a rational solution; that is, we have

$a = \dfrac{p}{q}, \; p, q \in \Bbb Z; \tag 4$

we may of course assume that

$\gcd(p, q) = 1; \tag 5$

then the equation

$a^2 = a + 1 \tag 6$

becomes

$\dfrac{p^2}{q^2} = \dfrac{p}{q} + 1, \tag 7$

whence upon multiplication by $q^2$,

$p^2 = pq + q^2; \tag 8$

one conclusion we may draw from this equation is

$p^2 = pq + q^2 = q(p + q) \Longrightarrow q \mid p^2. \tag 9$

We pause to note that

$a \notin \Bbb Z,  \tag{10}$

lest, as pointed out by our colleague hamam_Abdallah in his answer, we have

$a(a - 1) = 1, \tag{11}$

which implies either

$a, a - 1 = 1 \Longrightarrow a = 1 + 1 = 2 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow a = 1, \tag{12}$

or

$a, a - 1 = -1 \Longrightarrow a = -1 + 1 = 0$
$\Rightarrow \Leftarrow a = -1; \tag{13}$

it is manifestly evident that (12) and (13) are fallacious; thus (10) binds, and from this we see that

$q \ne 1; \tag{14}$

otherwise (10) doesn't apply.

Now

$\gcd(p, q) = 1 \Longrightarrow \exists a, b \in \Bbb Z, \; ap + bq = 1; \tag{15}$

multiplying by $p$ we obtain

$ap^2 + bqp = p, \tag{16}$

whence

$q \mid p^2 \Longrightarrow q \mid p \Rightarrow \Leftarrow \gcd(p, q) = 1 \tag{17}$

in light of (14); this final contradiction implies it is impossible to find $p$ and $q$ satisfying (4); we conclude that

$a \notin \Bbb Q, \tag{18}$

$OE\Delta$.